# interface covariance issue

Tags: c#-4.0, covariance

The following code sample:

```
interface I<out T>
    where T : class, I<T>
{
    T GetT();
}

interface J : I<J>
{
}

abstract class B<T> : I<T>
    where T : B<T>
{
    T I<T>.GetT()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class C : B<C>, J
{
}
```

fails to compile (under VS2010 with SP1) with the following error:

```
Error   4   'C' does not implement interface member 'I<J>.GetT()'
```

However, C does implement (through its base B<C>) I<C>, which, due to I being declared covariant, should capture I<J> as well (as C : J).

Is this a compiler bug? If not, why am I not allowed to do that?

Comment: I *suspect* it may be due to explicit interface implementation. Have you tried making `B<T>.GetT()` just public?

Comment: Yes, I have. The error remains, with the added comment that B's implementation has invalid return type to be a match (we don't have return type covariance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it is covariant, you *cannot change the return type of the interface*. This is no different from the covariance in non-Generic classes.

```
interface Animal
{
    Animal GetAnimal();
}

class Cat : Animal
{
   //Not ALlowed
   Cat GetAnimal()
   {
       return this;
   }

   //Allowed
   Animal GetAnimal()
   {
       return this;
   }   
}
```

The problem is that C as a specialization of `B<C>` returns `C I<C>.GetT()`, however the specification of J requires `J GetT()`.

Try the following:

```
interface I<out T>
    where T : class, I<T>
{
    T GetT();
}

interface J : I<J>
{
}

abstract class B<T,U> : I<U>
    where T : B<T,U>, U
    where U : class, I<U>
{
    U I<U>.GetT()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class C : B<C,J>, J
{
}
```

Comment: It seems then that variance is only useful "from the outside" - here `I<C>` is only **convertible** to `I<J>`, an implementation of the former is **not** an implementation of the latter. Am I correct?

Comment: @Grzegorz, you are asking another question. The reason the code doesn't compile has nothing to do with covariance, it has to do with the fact that CLR languages do not allow you to modify the signature of an interface method in an implementation - even if it is a constraint. Personally, I find the covariant feature for generics to be mostly useful when dealing with Generic collections. i.e. `IList<B> bList = new IList<C>(){};` (where C : B).

Comment: @Ethan: This compiles correctly: `interface I<out T>
{
    T GetT();
}

class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}

class C : I<B>
{
    B I<B>.GetT()
    {
        return null;
    }

    static void M()
    {
        I<A> ia = new C();
    }
}`. Here, the implementation of `I<B>` serves (automatically) as an implementation of `I<A>`, even though the return types of `GetT` are different. It is not clear (at least to me) why it should not work in the original case. And, by the way, IIRC `IList` is not covariant...

Comment: Moreover, if I add `I<A>` next to `I<B>`, the code fails to compile - even though the compiler was perfectly happy to treat an object of class `C` as `I<A>` until I explicitly said it is one!

Comment: It does not seem to be a compiler issue - mono-2.10.2 behaves exactly like VS on all of the above examples.

Comment: @Grzegorz, You are correct that it is not a compiler issue. Again, when you implement an interface, you must use the **EXACT** method signature defined in the interface. The only thing in your example in your comment that requires covariance be defined is the statement `I<A> ia = new C();`. If you omit this line, it will compile correctly without covariance defined. You cannot declare the return type as a Subtype of the original (even with covariance) and you cannot declare arguments as a supertype of the original (even with contravariance).

Comment: @Grzegorz, see my updated answer for an alternative solution that will allow you to use the abstract base class.

Comment: @Ethan, this is nice. Thanks :)