# C# covariance and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, covariance

I'm curious to know why the implementation of my interface in the abstract base class does not satisfy the the requirements in sub-classes.  Here's an example:

```
public interface IBase { }
public interface IConcrete : IBase { }

public interface IBaseManager<out T>
    where T : IBase
{
    T Create();
    IEnumerable<T> SelectAll();
}

public interface IConcreteManager : IBaseManager<IConcrete> { }

public abstract class Base : IBase { }

public class Concrete1 : Base, IConcrete { }

public abstract class BaseManager<T> : IBaseManager<T> where T : class, IBase
{
    #region IBaseManager<T> Members

    public T Create()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class ConcreteManager : BaseManager<Concrete>, IConcereteManager
{
             //error occurs here
}
```

This is the error that is being generated:

> 'ConsoleApplication4.ConcreteManager' does not implement interface member 'ConsoleApplication4.IBaseManager<ConsoleApplication4.IConcrete>.Create()'.
>
> 'ConsoleApplication4.BaseManager<ConsoleApplication4.Concrete>.Create()' cannot implement 'ConsoleApplication4.IBaseManager<ConsoleApplication4.IConcrete>.Create()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'ConsoleApplication4.IConcrete'.

If I add these methods to the `ConcreteManager` class, everything is fine and the compiler is happy.

```
public new IConcrete Create()
{
    return base.Create();
}

public new IEnumerable<IConcrete> SelectAll()
{
    return base.SelectAll();
}
```

If simply returning what the methods from the base class return is sufficient, why do the methods have to be added?  Why can't the compiler call the methods in the base class?

Comment: I expect extending the interface is the problem, try removing that.

Comment: don't you want `public class ConcreteManager : BaseManager<IConcrete>, IConcereteManager` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming return type covariance, since `ConcreteManager` (as an `IConcreteManager`) expects both `Create()` and `SelectAll()` methods with a return type of `IConcrete` and `IEnumerable<IConcrete>` respectively, which the base class does not provide.

You are getting those errors because C# does not support return type covariance.

Answer (score 7):

As John points out correctly, the C# language does not support return type covariance. Neither does the CLR, so even if the language supported it, the only way we could actually *implement* the feature would be to silently generate exactly the code you've had to add yourself.

The small benefit afforded to developers of avoiding having to write those stub methods really does not justify the considerable cost of doing the more general covariance feature, so we've never done it.

Comment: So would it be accurate to say that the covarience is acutally happening an assignment to the return value?

Comment: @Seattle Leonard: I don't understand the question. Covariance is the property that a *mapping* preserves the *direction* of a *relationship*. In the case of return type covariance, we have two relationships: assignment compatibility, and virtual slot compatibility. In languages where the mapping from types to methods returning those types is "covariant" with respect to those relationships, it is the case that if X is assignment-compatible with Y, then a method which returns X is virtual-slot-compatible with a method that returns Y.

Comment: @EricLippert I would not say covariant returns types were a small benefit afforded to developers. In my latest project, I added literally up to a hundred of these "invariant fixes". Or am I doing something wrong in general?

Comment: Implementing `IMyInterface` with `IOtherInterface` method/property for a better overview by `MyClass` with the `OtherClass` (derived from `IOtherInterface`) method/property, I always do need such a fix.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement an interface/abstract class, you must use the same signature. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6250676/759701)

Don't let the generics throw you off, this is no different than if there were no generics.